# Change all variables from specific Model using Reflection

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, entity, system.reflection

I have a big model that was generated from a Json File, and I added a field called Sigla_Container to all Classes. How can I set the value for all the fields with name Sigla_Container directly without needing to set one by one?

The Model is below:

```
public class ContainerViagemContainer
{
    [Key]
    [JsonProperty("Sigla")]
    public string Sigla_Container { get; set; }
    public object Descricao { get; set; }
    public int Tara { get; set; }
    public int Dimensao { get; set; }
    public object Tipo { get; set; }
}

public class ContainerViagemArmador
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [JsonProperty("Id")]
    public int Id_Armador { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("ContainerViagemContainer")]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public string Sigla_Container { get; set; }
    public virtual ContainerViagemContainer ContainerViagemContainer { get; set; }

    public object CodigoGeParcei { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Sigla { get; set; }
    public object CnpjCpf { get; set; }
    public object Endereco { get; set; }
    public object Cep { get; set; }
    public object Site { get; set; }
}

public class ContainerViagemNavio
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [JsonProperty("Nome")]
    public string Nome_Navio { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("ContainerViagemContainer")]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public string Sigla_Container { get; set; }
    public virtual ContainerViagemContainer ContainerViagemContainer { get; set; }

    public ContainerViagemArmador Armador { get; set; }
    public string ImagemNavio { get; set; }
    public double Comprimento { get; set; }
    public int Lloyd { get; set; }
    public string CallSign { get; set; }
    public int CapacidadeTeus { get; set; }
    public string Shortname { get; set; }
}

public class ContainerViagemJanelaAtracacao
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [JsonProperty("Descricao")]
    public string Descricao_JanelaAtracacao { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("ContainerViagemContainer")]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public string Sigla_Container { get; set; }
    public virtual ContainerViagemContainer ContainerViagemContainer { get; set; }

    public string Dia { get; set; }
    public string Inicio { get; set; }
    public string Fim { get; set; }
}

public class ContainerViagemBerco
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [JsonProperty("Ponto")]
    public string Ponto_Berco { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("ContainerViagemContainer")]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public string Sigla_Container { get; set; }
    public virtual ContainerViagemContainer ContainerViagemContainer { get; set; }

    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public string Sentido { get; set; }
    public ContainerViagemJanelaAtracacao JanelaAtracacao { get; set; }
}

public class ContainerViagemViagem
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [JsonProperty("Id")]
    public int Id_Viagem { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("ContainerViagemContainer")]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public string Sigla_Container { get; set; }
    public virtual ContainerViagemContainer ContainerViagemContainer { get; set; }

    public string NumeroAtracacao { get; set; }
    public string NumeroViagem { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Joint { get; set; }
    public string Servico { get; set; }
    public string MotivoEspera { get; set; }
    public string LiberacaoRecebimento { get; set; }
    public ContainerViagemNavio Navio { get; set; }
    public string ChegadaPrevista { get; set; }
    public string AtracacaoPrevista { get; set; }
    public string SaidaPrevista { get; set; }
    public string DeadLine { get; set; }
    public string Chegada { get; set; }
    public string Atracacao { get; set; }
    public string Saida { get; set; }
    public string InicioOperacao { get; set; }
    public string FimOperacao { get; set; }
    public string TipoOperacao { get; set; }
    public string CodigoCodesp { get; set; }
    public double CaladoAtracacao { get; set; }
    public object CaladoDesatracacao { get; set; }
    public string NumeroViagemImportacao { get; set; }
    public string NumeroViagemExportacao { get; set; }
    public ContainerViagemBerco Berco { get; set; }
    public int PrevisaoDescarga { get; set; }
    public int PrevisaoEmbarque { get; set; }
    public int PrevisaoRemocao { get; set; }
    public string LocalAtracacao { get; set; }
}

public class ContainerViagemCarreta
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public string PlacaCavalo { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public string PlacaReboque { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("ContainerViagemContainer")]
    [Column(Order = 3)]
    public string Sigla_Container { get; set; }
    public virtual ContainerViagemContainer ContainerViagemContainer { get; set; }

    public string Entrada { get; set; }
    public string Saida { get; set; }
    public int PesoEntrada { get; set; }
    public int PesoSaida { get; set; }
    public object CNH { get; set; }
    public object Motorista { get; set; }
}

public class ContainerViagemImportador
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [JsonProperty("Id")]
    public int Id_Importador { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("ContainerViagemContainer")]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public string Sigla_Container { get; set; }
    public virtual ContainerViagemContainer ContainerViagemContainer { get; set; }

    public object CodigoGeParcei { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public object Sigla { get; set; }
    public object CnpjCpf { get; set; }
    public object Endereco { get; set; }
    public object Cep { get; set; }
    public object Site { get; set; }
}

public class ContainerViagemBl
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [JsonProperty("Numero")]
    public string Numero_BL { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("ContainerViagemContainer")]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public string Sigla_Container { get; set; }
    public virtual ContainerViagemContainer ContainerViagemContainer { get; set; }

    public int Lote { get; set; }
    public ContainerViagemImportador Importador { get; set; }
    public object Despachante { get; set; }
    public object Armador { get; set; }
    public object Nvocc { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public string PresencaCarga { get; set; }
    public object DataEnvioPresCarga { get; set; }
    public object StatusEnvioPresCarga { get; set; }
    public object Recinto { get; set; }
    public object Setor { get; set; }
    public object Situacao { get; set; }
    public string Documento { get; set; }
    public object TipoDocumento { get; set; }
    public object DataDocumento { get; set; }
    public object DataArmazenagem { get; set; }
    public object Mercadorias { get; set; }
    public object Containers { get; set; }
    public object Viagem { get; set; }
    public object PortoOrigem { get; set; }
    public object QuantidadeContainers { get; set; }
    public object QuantidadeContainerEntradaTerminal { get; set; }
    public bool Bloqueio { get; set; }
    public object MotivoCaptacao { get; set; }
    public object Status { get; set; }
    public object Desembaraco { get; set; }
    public int CifMoedaOrig { get; set; }
    public object NumeroCE { get; set; }
}

public class ContainerViagemLacresEntrada
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [JsonProperty("Origem")]
    public string Origem_LacresEntrada { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("ContainerViagemContainer")]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public string Sigla_Container { get; set; }
    public virtual ContainerViagemContainer ContainerViagemContainer { get; set; }

    public string Verificado { get; set; }
    public string Tipo { get; set; }
    public object Status { get; set; }
}

public class ContainerViagemLacresSaida
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [JsonProperty("Origem")]
    public string Origem_LacresSaida { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("ContainerViagemContainer")]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public string Sigla_Container { get; set; }
    public virtual ContainerViagemContainer ContainerViagemContainer { get; set; }

    public string Verificado { get; set; }
    public string Tipo { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

public class ContainerViagemAvaria
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [JsonProperty("Local")]
    public string Local_Avaria { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    [JsonProperty("Tipo")]
    public string Tipo_Avaria { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("ContainerViagemContainer")]
    [Column(Order = 3)]
    public string Sigla_Container { get; set; }
    public virtual ContainerViagemContainer ContainerViagemContainer { get; set; }

    public string Complemento { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public string TermoAvaria { get; set; }
}

public class ContainerViagem
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID_ContainerViagem { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("ContainerViagemContainer")]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public string Sigla_Container { get; set; }
    public virtual ContainerViagemContainer ContainerViagemContainer { get; set; }

    public object IdCtis { get; set; }

    public ContainerViagemContainer Container { get; set; }

    public object Exportador { get; set; }
    public ContainerViagemViagem Viagem { get; set; }
    public int TipoViagem { get; set; }
    public string PortoOrigem { get; set; }
    public string PortoDestino { get; set; }
    public object PortoDestinoFinal { get; set; }
    public string Entrada { get; set; }
    public string Saida { get; set; }
    public object StatusScanner { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string StatusSigvig { get; set; }
    public int PesoManifCarga { get; set; }
    public int PesoManifTara { get; set; }
    public int PesoManifBruto { get; set; }
    public int PesoCarga { get; set; }
    public int PesoBruto { get; set; }
    public int DivergenciaPeso { get; set; }
    public double DivergenciaPesoPorcent { get; set; }
    public bool ExcessoDivergenciaPeso { get; set; }
    public ContainerViagemCarreta Carreta { get; set; }
    public IList<ContainerViagemBl> Bls { get; set; }
    public IList<ContainerViagemLacresEntrada> LacresEntrada { get; set; }
    public IList<ContainerViagemLacresSaida> LacresSaida { get; set; }
    public object TermoAvaria { get; set; }
    public IList<ContainerViagemAvaria> Avarias { get; set; }
    public object Temperatura { get; set; }
    public object SD { get; set; }
    public object Booking { get; set; }
    public object Agendamento { get; set; }
    public object Armador { get; set; }
    public object Imos { get; set; }
    public object Cheio { get; set; }
    public object Regime { get; set; }
    public object Documentos { get; set; }
    public IList<object> Desova { get; set; }
    public int HreqId { get; set; }
    public int TmodId { get; set; }
    public int PesoCargaVGM { get; set; }
    public int PesoTaraVGM { get; set; }
    public int PesoBrutoVGM { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, the field Sigla_Container is in all classes, I tried the code below to get these fields, but how can I set the value for these fields?

```
ContainerViagem containerViagem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ContainerViagem>(strToken["ContainerViagem"].ToString());
                        containerViagem.Container.Sigla_Container = container;

     foreach (var campoJson in containerViagem.GetType().GetProperties())
     {
          if (campoJson.Name.Equals("Sigla_Container"))
          {

          }
     }
```

Comment: I think the first question should be: why do you want this field everywhere? This type of redundancy is a maintenance hell.

Comment: I am deserializing a JSON file, but as the JSON has many blocks and arrays inside it, it defines that each block is a Table. The problem is that I should add a foreign key for all these tables and it would be the field Sigla_Container. I don't know how I could do this without needing to create a foreign key in each of the tables.

Comment: Well, if you store this structure using EF, EF will fill the FKs for you.

Comment: I tried this. I added the foreign key in all models but the when I try to add to dbcontext, the foreign keys are empty, they are not reflecting the value from primary key.

Comment: Yeah, well, I obviously don't know the content of your JSON. It the objects aren't related in the JSON, EF won't connect them for you and your only option is to set each property individually.

Answer (score 1):

Use [SetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194291(v=vs.110).aspx). Pass the object instance as the first parameter and the new value as the second.

```
campoJson.SetValue(containerViagem, "New value");
```

Comment: The problem is that it just set the value for Sigla_Container in the model ContainerViagem and I want to set all variables Sigla_Container.

Comment: If you want to populate more properties, remove or change the condition in ` if (campoJson.Name.Equals("Sigla_Container"))`.

Comment: But I tried to add this code:

`campoJson.SetValue(containerViagem, container);`

It will change the variable Sigla_Container just for the first Model ContainerViagem and not for the others called from it.

Comment: Is there a way that I could set the main variable Sigla_Container on root Model and then it would reflect and all the others Sigla_Container?